# Hasta Mudra done with the left hand affects the right side of the body and vice versa- I need a scriptural proof for this statement

Tags: yoga, mudra

"[Hasta Mudra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudra) done with the left hand affects the right side of the body and vice versa"

The [Yogaguru Swami Ramdev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramdev) had said that once on TV while taking a Yoga class.

Now, this is something that we can empirically verify. It really happens like that.

But i want verses from Scriptures and (or) Yoga treatises which prove this. This will help me settle an argument elsewhere.